# Com CSS é possível fazer um círculo vazado em uma imagem?

Tags: html, css, css3, imagem

Eu estava querendo colocar uma área "vazada" na imagem, de forma que na imagem tenha uma área vazia e que eu possa ver o `background` que está por de traz dessa imagem.

Exemplo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu consegui chegar até aqui, mas não consigo colocar a imagem na borda. Minha ideia inicial seria colocar a imagem só na borda de uma `div` sem preenchimento. Mas não sei se esse é o caminho.

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, blue);
    background-size: contain;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
}
.bola {
    height: 40vh;
    width: 40vh;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 10vh solid;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bola"></div>
```

Comment: Veja esse link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706963/possible-to-use-border-radius-together-with-a-border-image-which-has-a-gradient

Comment: @caiocafardo é parece que a forma mais "fácil" seria com SVG. mas ainda estou tentando só com CSS...

Comment: É, já passei por isso e fui pro svg, o problema é o radius, né?

Comment: @caiocafardo exato, não aplica o radius

Answer (score 6):

Consegui algumas soluções interessantes, umas "mais" *crossbrowser* usando `background-attackment` e outras menos *crossbrowser* com `-webkit-mask-image` e `mix-bland-mode`. Também seria possível fazer com SVG, mas não vou entrar nesse mérito e vou ficar só no CSS.

### Opção 1

É a mais simples de aplicar e de entender. A ideia aqui é fazer uma mascara usando um `radial-gradiente` na `-webkit-mask-image`. Radial pq a imagem é redonda, mas funciona com `linear-gradiente` tb.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O importante aqui é saber que a cor `branca` vai esconder tudo que estiver nela e a cor `preta` vai mostrar. Como o `radial-gradiente` é do branco até 40% e depois preto o "miolo" da imagem fica oculto e só aparece uma fração referente ao 60% do preto. Veja o resultado!

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=912);
    background-size: 200% 200%;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    position: relative;

    background-position: center center;
    animation: bg 10s linear infinite;
}

img {
    border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-mask-image: radial-gradient(circle, transparent 40%, black 41%);
  object-fit: cover;
    width:auto;
    height:75%
}


@keyframes bg {
    50% {
        background-position-y: -100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300?image=896" alt="">
```

---

### Opção 2

Essa opção vai usar dois elementos. Imagine que vc tem um background no `Body`, ai vc tem o `filho 1` e o `filho 2` por cima desse `filho 1`, o `filho 2` vai ter as mesmas propriedades de `background` que o `Body`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Basicamente é isso e vc vai ter o efeito como se a imagem fosse vazada!

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(red, blue);
    background-size: 400% 400%;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    position: relative;

    background-position: center center;
    animation: bg 10s linear infinite;
}
img {
    border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-mask-image: radial-gradient(circle, transparent 50%, black 50%);
}

.box1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 40vh;
    height: 40vh;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-image: url(https://placecage.com/300/300);
    background-size: cover;
}
.box2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20vh;
    height: 20vh;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(red, blue);
    background-size: 400% 400%;
    background-attachment: fixed;

    background-position: center center;
    animation: bg 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes bg {
    50% {
        background-position-y: -200%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="box1"></div>
<div class="box2"></div>
```